# X3d model not Loading using Inline, error in x3dom.js

Tags: x3d, x3dom

I am very new to x3dom, I am trying to display a 3d model on the web. I created the model in FreeCAD, exported to wrl format, and then converted to x3d using whitedune. Most of my models are displaying, but sometimes randomly) it just keeps on showing Loading and nothing happens.
In the below example, the first model works. Then I make slight modifications and again create a new x3d file, but it doesn't display.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zz99d1snxnvl2yh/working.x3d?dl=0 (working)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/inf3k5jxp4qra2p/notWorking.x3d?dl=0 (Not Working)

Looking in the console, the error I get is 
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'r' of undefined' in line 3848 of x3dom.js.
Here's the js file I am using
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pblpt563v5adx9/x3dom.js?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

All of these links report 404 (not found).

Usually the reason something does not load in X3DOM is the X3D code is trying to access a resource from a different server the the parent HTML. The best solution is to make sure that you use only local or relative paths (no protocol, no host, no domain) to those resources. If that still does not solve the problem please expand with working URLs.

Comment: I removed these links after a couple of days. I found the problem to be in the x3dom.js file. It was going into an if loop, that it shouldn't have. I added an extra condition, now all my models work.

Comment: @Mancunia89, could you tell me where in the x3dom.js file you made the modifications? I am probably experiencing the same problem as you!

Comment: Hi people from the past! If you don't mind sharing your solution, nowadays in the pandemic year, it still happens to me that <inline> loading randomly doesn't work